# CSV manipulaions with python

Tags: python, csv, iterator

For my purposes i have to know the number of lines in the (CSV) file before actually working with rows. I have googled and found that documentation says that i should create an iterator (CSV.reader) for two times (first one for counting and the second for working with rows). Is this the only way or maybe there is some tricky method to do a trick?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: first we need to understand why do you need number of rows before working with them

Comment: If number of rows > N (where N is different for every user) i should not process the file.

Comment: It least for me it look like there is no other ways to do this - in any case read all lines and proceed all lines are different things - so i'd suggest you to read all than check in size and if it ok proceed with lines - otherwise switch to the next file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your file is not very big than you can try:

```
from csv import reader

def proceed(size):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = list(csv.reader(f))
        if len(data) > size:
            return
        else:
            for line in data:
                #do action


weights = {'user1': 4, 'user2': 5}  
for k,v in weights.iteritems():
    proceed(v)
```

Or as suggested by @georgesl in case when you have a very big file:

```
def proceed(size):
    if sum(1 for row in csv.reader(open(filename))) > size:
        return
    else:
        for line in csv.reader(open(filename)):
            #do action
```

Comment: What is the appropriate size of a file? What about 100KB?

Comment: if your files are big, maybe `row_count = sum(1 for row in csv.reader( open('filename.csv') ) ) ` is better for the size

Comment: @alexvassel The appropriate file size is anything that won't put your machine in a coma - a 1gb CSV file probably won't stress most modern machines...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way without reading the file, but depending on where your bottlenecks are you could just process *N* lines, and if there is more discard them, for example:

```
count = 0
for line in reader:
    count += 1
    if count > N:  # Over the limit so stop processing
        break
    else:
        processed_data += process(line)
else:
    # This block only runs if the loop completed naturally, i.e. count <= N
    return processed_data
```

If `process(line)` is expensive, then your best bet may be to use two loops as described in your question.